# How to update TYPO3 default language by using a translation server?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

The given setup is a translation server that follows the rules described in [TYPO3 Docs: ManagingTranslations](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Internationalization/ManagingTranslations.html#custom-translation-servers). The problem is, that we need to synchronize the default language (*en*) as well but there is no option for *en* in the Maintenance-Backend-Module. What do I need to to update the file locallang.xlf or en.locallang.xlf?

Comment: The default language files (without the language prefix) are always shipped with the TYPO3 core or the extension.

Comment: You're right about that. In our case, however, we separate the creation of translations from the development of extensions. So we don't have any translation files in the extensions. This works with translations into other languages excellent, such as German for example, but not for English.